# how to have a custom drawer layout with recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

i want to create a custom drawer layout and have a recycler view inside it, how can i do this so all recycler view rows show inside the drawer layout and make it scrollable, i.e i want to show the whole `FoodListFragment` in the drawer.

my drawer layout

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

my recycler view which is inside a fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:context=".FoodListFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the whole `FoodListFragment` to be the drawer? Or do you want the drawer inside `FoodListFragment`?

Comment: yes i want `FoodListFragment` to be the drawer.

Comment: OK, then inside the `<DrawerLayout>`, after the main content, you could simply add `<fragment android:name="your.package.name.FoodListFragment" android:layout_width="240dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start|left" />`. That instance will be loaded automagically for you, so you don't need to do any `FragmentTransaction` for it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding your fragment inside `DrawerLayout`. Check below:

**First,** Create a container for your fragment inside `DrawerLayout`

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Then**, Attach your fragment in this container using `FragmentTransaction`

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FoodListFragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please don't suggest that users put other `<View>`s inside a `<NavigationView>`. It's really not meant to be used like that. `NavigationView` has a very specific internal structure that it builds itself dynamically. Also, the drawer in a `DrawerLayout` doesn't have to be a `NavigationView`. It can be pretty much any `View` or `ViewGroup` that you want, so there's really no need to use `<NavigationView>` just as a container.

Comment: thank you guys, it worked but the is not scrollable!, how can i fix this ?

Comment: @hiwajalal, I have checked, it scrolling. Do you have enough items to scroll?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman yes i have many items for scrolling, here is my current drawer layout https://pastebin.com/nYSYSf3J

Comment: Put your `drawer_fragment_container ` at the bottom of the `DrawerLayout`. Check my updated answer

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman oh yes i just checked that and yeah now it works perfectly, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

add following code in your drawer layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:id="@+id/nv">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

in your MainActivity

```
private NavigationView nv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nv = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch(id)
            {
                case R.id.account:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                case R.id.mycart:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }


            return true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: where am i adding the fragment to the drawer ?

Comment: add frame layout in your drawer layout